# Join a multiple tables get clone only demand not supply

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity

```
  Plantdemand
 Id | FId   | FY        
 ------------------
 22 | 1     | 2011-15


 No.PlantDemand
Id | PDId | CId | Demand
------------------------
1  | 22   |  1  | 100
2  | 22   |  2  | 200
3  | 22   |  3  | 300
      ^
      "- Id of plantDemand 

 PlantSupply
Id  | FId   | DId  | FY
---------------------
11  | 1     | 22   | 2012-13
               ^
               "-Id of plantDemand


 No.PlantSuply
ID  | PSId | CId | Supply
---------------------------
1   | 11   | 1   | 10
2   | 11   | 2   | 10
       ^
       "--Id of PlantSupply
```

I am stuck to get a CId entries not in table No.PlantSupply of FId=1 like to get a clone who demand enter but not supplied

```
      var getNoofPlantDemand = (from r in getdemand
                                          join nd in context.tbl_NoOfPlantDemanded on r.PlantDemandId equals nd.PlantDemandId into list1
                                          from l1 in list1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          join p in context.PlantationTypes on r.PlantationTypeId equals p.Id into list3
                                          from l3 in list3.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                          select new
                                          {}).toList()


var getCloneDemand = (from r in getNoofPlantDemand
                                      join cl in context.Clones on r.CloneId equals cl.Id into list4
                                      from l4 in list4.DefaultIfEmpty()


var getPlantSupply = (from r in getCloneDemand
                                         join s in context.PlantSupply on r.PlantDemandId equals s.DemandId into list

                                         from l1 in list.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                         join ns in context.No.PlantSupply on l1.Id equals ns.PSId into list1
                                         from l2 in list1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                         where r.CloneId != l2.CloneId && r.PlantDemandId==l1.DemandId && r.PlantationTypeId == l2.PlantationTypeId
                                         select new
                                         {}).toList()


 my requirement:

Id | FId  | FY       | CId | Demand 
22 | 1    | 2011-012 | 3   | 300
```

Please let me know if anybody know how can i get the clone those are not supplied only a demand entry